# How do I manage what resources are copied to my build product in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Using Xcode 3, I could expand the active target group in the "Groups & Files" column and explicitly add or remove bundle resources from my product.

Using Xcode 4, I created a few text files which I want to read from my build product's bundle at runtime.

When I inspect my build product's bundle, I see Xcode 4 is not adding these files to my build product even though the "Target Membership" inspector of the text files indicates the files are associated with the active target.

Using Xcode 4, how do I manage what resources are copied to the bundle during the build process?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Choose "View" > "Navigators" > "Project".
2. Select the project icon.
3. Select the active target in the detail view.
4. Choose the "Build Phases" segment towards the top centre of the detail view.
5. Expand the group labelled "Copy Bundle Resources".

Comment: Thank you! All the other answers I've found from Googling have been terrible. maybe from an outdated version of Xcode.